# Matlab identity shift matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

Is there any inline command to generate shifted identity matrix in MATLAB?

```
A=[ ...
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

combination of `circshift` and `eye` is good however it needs another command to fix it. Any simpler way? (with just one simple syntax)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using a [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) call in combination with [`ones`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html).  For your case, you have a 10 x 10 identity matrix and want to shift the diagonal to the right by 1.

```
>> n = 10;
>> shift = 1;
>> A = diag(ones(n-abs(shift),1),shift)

A = 

   0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
   0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
   0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
   0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
   0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
   0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

---

The above code works by first declaring a column vector of all 1s, but we would need `n-abs(shift)` of them as moving to the right would mean that we would require less 1s to fill things up (more on this later).  `n-abs(shift)` also corresponds to the total number of rows/columns of your matrix and subtracting out as many times you are shifting towards the right.  Next, you can use `diag` where the first parameter is a column vector which creates a **zero** matrix and places the column vector as coefficients along the diagonal of this matrix.  The second parameter (`shift` in your case) allows you to **offset** where to place this column.  Specifying a positive value means to move the diagonals towards the right, and in our case we are moving this to the right by `shift`, and hence our output results.  As you are essentially truncating the vector for each position towards the right you are moving, you would need to decrease the number of 1s in your vector by this much.

Up to now, I haven't explained why the `abs` call to `shift` is required in the last line of code.  The reason why the `abs` call is required is to accommodate for negative shifts.  If we didn't have the `abs` call in the third line of code, `n-shift` would essentially be **adding** more 1s to the vector and would thus expand our matrix beyond `n x n`.  Because moving the diagonals to the left also decreases the amount of 1s seen in the result, that's why the `abs` call is required but you'll notice that the `shift` constant is left untouched in the second parameter of `diag`.

Here's a demonstration with a negative shift, `shift = -1`, and still maintaining the size to be 10 x 10:

```
A =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: Just adding that it should be `diag(ones(n-1,1),1)`

Comment: @zahmati - Ah! thanks!  I generalized it for any value `shift`.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the desired output with a single call to [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
n = 10
shift = 1
A = bsxfun(@eq,[1:n].',1-shift:n-shift)
```

Since you are basically creating a sparse matrix, alternatively you can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) -

```
n = 10
shift = 1
A = full(sparse(1:n-shift,1+shift:n,1,n,n))
```

Comment: The `sparse` approach is very nice!

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah ! That just strike me! :)

Comment: Sweet :) Also saw that you generalized it for any shift value.  Cool!

Comment: @rayryeng Yup! You were the inspiration behind that! ;)

Answer (score 7):

way late in this game but let us not forget the simplest solution using linear indexing:

```
n=10; a=zeros(n);
a(n+1:n+1:end)=1
```

obviously, that just solves the shift=1 case, but you get the point...

Comment: Nice +1 BTW, you could multiply the initial `n` with `shift` to generalize it. Like this: `a(shift*n+1:n+1:end)=1` Although it does only works for positive values

Comment: Nice. Wondered how to do this by just linear indexing as well.

Comment: it also work with negativ value: for example for a -4 shift: `a((1+4):n+1:end-n*(4-1))=1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `circshift` and fix the matrix before passing it to the function:

```
>> shift = 1;
>> N=10;
>> A=circshift(diag(1:N>shift),-shift)
A =
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

`1:N>shift` will be `0` for fist `shift` number of places and `1` for the remaining.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Another Alternative: (little similar to `bsxfun` Approach by Divakar)

```
n=10;
shift = 1;
c = repmat(1-shift:n-shift,n,1,1);
r = repmat((1:n).',1,n,1);
out = r == c
```

This could also be a one-liner:

```
out = repmat((1:n).',1,n,1) == repmat(1-shift:n-shift,n,1,1)
```

Comment: Nice job with logical comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one (also works with negative shifts)

```
rot90(blkdiag(zeros(abs(shift)),rot90(eye(n))),sign(shift))
```