# USE DIFFERENTIAL MATRIX OPERATOR TO SOLVE ODE

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-methods, differential-equations, differentiation

We were asked to define our own differential operators on MATLAB, and I did it following a series of steps, and then we should use the differential operators to solve a boundary value problem:

**-y'' + 2y' - y = x, y(0) = y(1) =0**

my code was as follows, it was used to compute [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970478/finding-numerical-derivative-using-a-shift-matrix-in-matlab) (first and second derivative)

```
h = 2;
x = 2:h:50; 
y = x.^2 ;

n=length(x);
uppershift = 1; 
U = diag(ones(n-abs(uppershift),1),uppershift);
lowershift = -1;
L= diag(ones(n-abs(lowershift),1),lowershift);
% the code above creates the upper and lower shift matrix


D  = ((U-L))/(2*h); %first differential operator 
D2 = (full (gallery('tridiag',n)))/ -(h^2); %second differential operator

d1= D*y.'
d2= ((D2)*y.')
```

then I changed it to this after posting it here and getting one response that encouraged the usage of Identity Matrix, however I still seem to be getting no where.

```
h = 2;

n=10;
uppershift = 1; 
U = diag(ones(n-abs(uppershift),1),uppershift);
lowershift = -1;
L= diag(ones(n-abs(lowershift),1),lowershift);


D  = ((U-L))/(2*h); %first differential operator 
D2 = (full (gallery('tridiag',n)))/ -(h^2); %second differential operator


I= eye(n);

eqn=(-D2 + 2*D - I)*y == x

solve(eqn,y)
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this, like should I define y and x, or what exactly? I am clueless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a **numerical** approximation to the solution of the ODE, you are seeking to find a numerical vector that is representative of the solution to this ODE from time `x=0` to `x=1`.  This means that your boundary conditions make it so that the solution is only valid between 0 and 1.

Also this is now the **reverse** problem.  [In the previous post we did together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970478/finding-numerical-derivative-using-a-shift-matrix-in-matlab), you know what the input vector was, and doing a matrix-vector multiplication produced the output derivative operation on that input vector.  Now, you are given the **output of the derivative** and you are now seeking what the **original input was**.  This now involves solving a linear system of equations.

Essentially, your problem is now this:

```
YX = F
```

`Y` are the coefficients from the matrix derivative operators that you derived, which is a `n x n` matrix, `X` would be the solution to the ODE, which is a `n x 1` vector and `F` would be the function you are associating the ODE with, also a `n x 1` vector.  In our case, that would be `x`.  To find `Y`, you've pretty much done that already in your code.  You simply take each matrix operator (first and second derivative) and you add them together with the proper signs and scales to respect the left-hand side of the ODE.   BTW, your first derivative and second derivative matrices are correct.  What's left is adding the `-y` term to the mix, and that is accomplished by `-eye(n)` as you have found out in your code.

Once you formulate your `Y` and `F`, you can use the [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) or `\` operator and solve for `X` and get the solution to this linear system via:

```
X = Y \ F;
```

The above essentially solves the linear system of equations formed by `Y` and `F` and will be stored in `X`.

The first thing you need to do is define a vector of points going from `x=0` to `x=1`.  [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) is probably the most suitable where you can specify how many points we want.  Let's assume 100 points for now:

```
x = linspace(0,1,100);
```

Therefore, `h` in our case is just `1/100`.  In general, if you want to solve from the starting point `x = a` up to the end point `x = b`, the step size `h` is defined as `h = (b - a)/n` where `n` is the total number of points you want to solve for in the ODE.

Now, we have to include the boundary conditions.  This simply means that we know the beginning and ending of the solution of the ODE.  This means that `y(0) = y(1) = 0`.  As such, we make sure that the first row of `Y` has only the first column set to 1 and the last row of `Y` has only the last column set to 1, and we'll set the output position in `F` to both be 0.  This symbolizes that we already know the solution at these points.

Therefore, your final code to solve is just:

```
%// Setup
a = 0; b = 1; n = 100;
x = linspace(a,b,n);
h = (b-a)/n;

%// Your code
uppershift = 1;
U = diag(ones(n-abs(uppershift),1),uppershift);
lowershift = -1;
L= diag(ones(n-abs(lowershift),1),lowershift);
D  = ((U-L))/(2*h); %first differential operator
D2 = (full (gallery('tridiag',n)))/ -(h^2);

%// New code - Create differential equation matrix
Y = (-D2 + 2*D - eye(n));

%// Set boundary conditions on system
Y(1,:) = 0; Y(1,1) = 1;
Y(end,:) = 0; Y(end,end) = 1;

%// New code - Create F vector and set boundary conditions
F = x.';
F(1) = 0; F(end) = 0;

%// Solve system
X = Y \ F;
```

`X` should now contain your numerical approximation to the ODE in steps of `h = 1/100` starting from `x=0` up to `x=1`.

Now let's see what this looks like:

```
figure; 
plot(x, X);
title('Solution to ODE');
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
```

[image]

You can see that `y(0) = y(1) = 0` as per the boundary conditions.

---

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! i literally lost hope last minute, then you popped in my head, thanks again!

Comment: @32px - ahaha no problem :) Numerical methods is one research area I specialize in.  If you have questions about that, pop by here and ask.  Make sure you send me a message through one of our previous posts so I get the message, like you did last time.  Good luck!

Comment: I sure will, also do you have any piece of advice or a helpful link I can read through to help expand my knowledge in this field?

Comment: I used to teach the course back when I was in university pursuing my PhD.  You're more than welcome to consult my notes on the labs: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t4xj9zpt8l14dri/AAAj1qpwhe5kvXDyUF5SVAG2a?dl=0.  Also, it may be prudent to check out my advanced MATLAB tutorial slides.  They may also prove to be of some help: http://www.slideshare.net/rayryeng1/advanced-matlab-tutorial-for-engineers-scientists

Comment: @32px - I made a slight error with the system. Forgot to take the `y'` terms and multiply by 2.  Updated the code and resulting plot.

Comment: I will make sure to check them, I am really thankful for your hard work and sorry if it happened to bother you or get in your way!

Comment: @32px - haha no problem.  One thing I love to do is spread knowledge around!  Wasn't an imposition at all.  They were easy links to access.  BTW, make sure you refresh the page.  I forgot to multiply the `y'` terms by 2 and that changed the plot slightly.

Comment: @32px - BTW, you should have enough reputation to upvote :) I would appreciate if you could also upvote my answer too!

Comment: Yes, I did refresh it, have a really nice day wherever you are and god bless you!! :)

Comment: I tried upvoting, but i guess I just earned enough reputation yay so I did now :)